# Jenkins - How to change file details

Tags: jenkins

In Jenkins, how can I change file details during the build process?

[image: Change file details]

I am developing an application in Delphi and would like to make a build process that puts the build number in product version and change some other properties.

Answer (score 0):

you should add a bash step / windows batch  that update the relevant file than you can build your application.

what is the flow that you are using for build ?

Comment: Thank´s Mor Lajb

The building does fine, except that the file build number does not get the number correct.

I am doing the build ina  Windows environment, so I have do do a batch.

Do you have a example of batch file that change the file properties?

Comment: So you have a properties file that need to update , since I am not a windows expert you can use groovy to update the file or use a batch script to do it.